# <a href> automatically adding www to site url by GIthub

Tags: html, heroku, hyperlink, github-pages

I have linked a project I made on heroku to another application made as a Github Page. My code is as follows:

`<a href="http://msitproject.herokuapp.com">Project</a>`

When I click on the link Github automatically prefixes it with www. But my application on heroku cannot be accessed by adding "www" as prefix. That is,

msitproject.herokuapp.com  [works]

www.msitproject.herokuapp.com  [doesn't work]

How can I prevent Github from adding "www"

Comment: No browser should ever do that... which browser are you using? Do you have any extensions installed? Can you look at the DOM after the page is rendered and check the URL - what is it? If all of these come back as expected you can debug the javascript running on the page to see if this is changing something or look at the network traffic to see which requests your browser is actually making (using fiddler or some developer tools extension with your browser)

Comment: The browser will not do this - the server it's connecting to will be the culprit.

Comment: My page is made using "Github Pages" and the target application is on "Heroku"

Comment: I think Github prefixes links with "www" how can I remove it?

Comment: I have edited the question to make it easier to understand

Comment: the interesting part is your github page. Can you give us an url ?

Comment: Here's the link for my [github page](http://www.rohitbegani.me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking in your [index.html code](https://github.com/rohitbegani/rohitbegani.github.io/blob/master/index.html), I found this :

```
<a href="msitproject.heroku.com"><h4 class="project-name">Bulletin App</h4></a>
```

It is supposed to be this :

```
<a href="http://msitproject.heroku.com"><h4 class="project-name">Bulletin App</h4></a>
```

Comment: Thanks @David Jacquel. I think I tried this before, don't know why it didn't work at that time. :/